Prove the quadratic form $\langle a^2+b^2, a^2+b^2-c^2\rangle$ always represents 1 (Over any field F).
I am currently studying quadratic forms with "Introduction to Quadratic Forms Over Fields" by Lam, and I found this interesting problem on proving a specific quadratic form always represent the number 1. The problem goes like this:
Let $F$ be a field such that $0 \neq a^2 + b^2 \neq c^2$ in $F$. Consider the quadratic form defined by:
$\langle a^2 + b^2, a^2 + b^2 - c^2 \rangle$
The problem is as follows:
Show that the quadratic form $\langle a^2 + b^2, a^2 + b^2 - c^2 \rangle$ always represents $1$ over $F$. That is, there exist $x, y \in F$ such that:
$
(a^2 + b^2)x^2 + (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)y^2 = 1.
$
I have little experience with quadratic forms, as I am only studying this topic by myself. I found another challenging problems in the book but I always managed to find a way with theorems or something, but this excecise makes me feel like I am missing something. I hope someone could give me a nice solution of this problem, even if it uses some knowledge deeper into this area. This is the first chapter of the book, so I think it should not be something really technical. Also, a professor hace this problem on his notes with a liitle suggestion saying "it sufices to show that the form represents any square". Any help or idea is appreciated.
Edit: The problem is found on page 24, excercise 21 on the first chapter in this book.

page 24, exercise 21.

yes, what do you mean with this...?

He means that you did not fully cite the problem you are asking about.

You want to show that there exists $x,y$ s.t. $(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=1+c^2y^2$, that is $(ax-by)^2+(ay+bx)^2=1+(cy)^2$.
Hence, one could try to see if at least one of the system of equations
$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lll}ax-by&=&1\cr bx+(a+\varepsilon c)y&=&0\end{array}\right.$ has a solution ($\varepsilon=\pm1$).
The determinant of the system is $a^2+b^2+\varepsilon ac$. If $a\neq 0$, since $c\neq 0$, then $ac\neq 0$, and these two numbers cannot be both zero. Thus, at least  one of the system has a solution.
If $a=0$, you are interested in solving $b^2x^2+b^2y^2=1+c^2y^2$.
One may take $x=b^{-1}$ and $y=0$ in this case.
